# Is there a way of making an md5sum of all files in subfolders?

Tags: bash, md5, sha256, md5sum

I have several exports of telegram data and I would like to calculate the md5 and sha256 hash of all files but it only calculates those in the root directory

`` $ md5sum `ls` > hash.md5 ``

```
md5sum: chats: Is a directory
md5sum: css: Is a directory
md5sum: images: Is a directory
md5sum: js: Is a directory
md5sum: lists: Is a directory
md5sum: profile_pictures: Is a directory
```

This is in the output file

```
7e315ce28aa2f6474e69a7b7da2b5886  export_results.html
66281ec07a2c942f50938f93b47ad404  hash.md5
da5e2fde21c3e7bbbdb08a4686c3d936  ID.txt
```

There is a way to get something like this out?

```
5750125fe13943f6b265505b25828400  js/script.js
```

*Sorry for my english*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With bash:

```
shopt -s globstar
md5sum ** >/tmp/hash.md5
```

Ignore errors of the kind: `md5sum: foobar: Is a directory`

From `man bash`:

> `globstar`: If set, the pattern ** used in a pathname expansion context will match all files and zero or more  directories and subdirectories. If the pattern is followed by a /, only directories and subdirectories match.

Comment: Don't get to use `**` enough!. But I assume that `**` is subject to cmd-line limitaions of the shell and if too many or too long filenames may generate the dreaded 'too many arguments' error. Just an FYI to O.P. Good luck to all!

Comment: @shellter: Yes, it may lead to "argument list too long" or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can use `find` with `-exec` option:

```
find topdir -type f -exec md5sum {} + > MD5SUMS
```

Replace the `topdir` with the actual directory name, or drop it if you want  to work on the current directory (and its subdirectories, if any). This will only compute the checksums of regular files (so, no "*md5sum: something: Is a directory*" errors), and won't suffer from the "*argument list too long*" problem.

Comment: `{ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -execdir md5sum {} +;} >md5sums.txt`

Comment: @LéaGris Why `-maxdepth 1`? The OP wants to compute checksums in subdirectories as well. And what's the point of curly brackets?

Comment: Right, remove `-maxdepth 1`. The `-execdir` stays as it allow to compute the md5sums of all files in same directory at once.

Comment: @LéaGris *The -execdir stays as it allow to compute the md5sums of all files in same directory at once*. So does `-exec`. I didn't understand your point.

Comment: You are right, it just `cd` to the directory before feeding the files as arguments which is a penalty here, as it will run `md5sum` for each directory rather than once for all files if it fits the maximum arguments length.

Answer (score 3):

A tool which helps, but might not be installed by default, is `hashdeep`.
`hashdeep` does it directly and has some more advantages, e.g. binary is available for Windows, too.

Your question would be answered using `hashdeep` with this command:

```
hashdeep -c md5,sha256 -r -o f -l . > hash.md5
```

This calculates md5 and sha256 of all files in all subdirs with one command.

Creating md5 and sha256 together might be faster due to caching effects of the files. Additionally the command has an option to use multiple threads, which could fasten up the task with multi-core CPUs and fast disks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following to achieve the task.

```
find . -type f -exec md5sum {} + >> log_checksum.txt

#. (dot) can be replaced with the location you need to run the command

#curly braces {} to mention, filenames of the command output will be passed to the md5sum command as arguments

#(+) plus sign is added to make sure files are passed as arguments to a single md5sum command, to prevent running a separate md5sum process for each file
```

Comment: basically the same as Aydin's answer, why do you reciprocate it?